# Angular - how to tell the difference between prod and dev for user

Tags: angular

Im working on an angular project and I have two separate links, one for dev and one prod, for testing different functionalities but I want to be able to change some css for one environment so the user who's testing can know what link he used if he miss clicked the other one. If there is an easier method to do the same thing but you dont need to change css is ok, i just need to show something in gui.

I tried making two css files and then i added them on `angular.json` for each configuration like this but this didnt work

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/styledev.css"
          ]
        }
```

Comment: You can use fileReplacements, see https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements. The example gives environment.ts but you can use it for styles

Answer (score 2):

Creation of different environment file is a better approach

for e.g creating `environments/dev.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  devMode: true,
  css: [
    './styles/dev.css',
  ],
};
```

and one for production like `environment/prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  devMode: false,
  css: [
    './styles/prod.css',
  ],
};
```

Then you can use the `environment` variable to load the appropriate CSS file.

Method 1: *(Prefered way)*
use the `ng serve` command with the `--configuration` flag.

This flag allows you to specify the environment that you want to use when serving your application.

Method 2: *(have not tested it but as per my understanding it should work)*

In `app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    environment.css,
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using a variable that i assigned the `isDevMode()` then in the html file i used this

```
<mat-toolbar *ngIf="dev === true" style="background-color: red;" color="primary">
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-toolbar *ngIf="dev === false" color="primary">
</mat-toolbar>
```

now the user can know in which environment is testing